# How can IntelliJ zip my project source files after making the jar file?

Tags: intellij-idea, build, zip

I've updated File->Project Structure adding jar as an Artifact.

I noticed I can use a custom "Other" artifact to copy my whole project folder to another destination. Unfortunately they are not zipped at the destination, and I don't see how to make this happen.

How can I copy them into a zip file automatically, so when I am done I can upload the zip and jar off of my computer more easily, instead of manually zipping or uploading the directory recursively.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you create a new Artifact of type Other. Then click the create the Archive button (it is next to the new directory button) and give it a name, project.zip for example. Right click the new zip entry under 'output root' and select 'add copy of' and then 'directory content'. Browse to your project directory and select it in the file picker. Click Apply and that should work.

It should look something like the screenshot below. 
[image: Create zip archive.]
Now just build the Artifact in the usual way.

Comment: Thanks! For my project I created a directory within the zip before adding the directory contents.